# Trying to make this work with two characters and not just one

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
    result = ""
    cards = ["2","3","5","5","J"]
    previous = cards[0]
    current = cards[1]

    i = 1
    while i < len(cards) and result == "" :

        previous = cards[i - 1]
        current = cards[i]

        if current == previous:
            result = result + current
            result = result + previous
        i = i + 1

    print(result)

main()
```

#Need this to work with 2 characters as in instead of the number list i would like `["2D","3C","5H","5D","JS"]`, But I'm not sure how to do it...

Comment: Could you explain what your code does. Also I ran it and it didn't even do anything, are you wanting a fix?

Comment: It's suppose to print 55 but i think while trying to modify the code i messed something up

Comment: probably should be this then `previous = cards[i-1]`

Comment: Yeah that's what i did

Comment: But I'd like advice how to use it using 2 characters like ["2D","3C","5H","5D","JS"]

Comment: You want `5H5D` as the output because the first number matches?

Comment: Yes that's what I'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String objects support indexing. For example

```
string = 'ABC123'
string[0]   | 'A'
string[-1]  | '3'
string[0:3] | 'ABC'
```

So by using `if current[0] == previous[0]:` you are checking the first value of the strings.

```
def main():
    result = ""
    cards = ["2D","3C","5H","5D","JS"]
    previous = cards[0]
    current = cards[1]

    i = 1
    while i < len(cards) and result == "":

        previous = cards[i-1]
        current = cards[i]

        if current[0] == previous[0]:
            result = previous + current

        i = i + 1

    print(result)

main()
```

Comment: This isn't pythonic at all.

Comment: The answer or his method?

Comment: Well.. both, frankly.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `previous = [i-1]` you forgot to put the `cards[i-1]`

If you want to put the two digits, but compare only the number of your cards, you can just compare the first char of the string:

```
if current[0] == previous[0]:
    result = result + current
    result = result + previous
```

This printed to me 5D5H

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more Pythonic solution which uses [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

> ## test.py

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def main():
    result = ""
    cards = ["2D","3C","5H","5D","JS"]

    # Generate adjacent pairs
    for prev, curr in pairwise(cards):
      # Append `prev` to `curr` if the first character is the same.
      if prev[0] == curr[0]:
        result = curr + prev

    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The function `pairwise` will take an iterable, `s = ["s0", "s1", "s2", "s3"]`, which can be iterated over by two elements that are adjacent. That said, you can look at the "current" and the "next" or the "previous" and the "current". I chose `prev` and `curr` because `next` is a keyword in Python (see its use in `pairwise`, actually).

You can do something like

```
for prev, curr in pairwise(s):
  print("prev: {}, curr: {}".format(prev, curr))
```

This would print:

```
prev: s0, curr: s1
prev: s1, curr: s2
prev: s2, curr: s3
```

You can then check the first element of each string with string indexing.

```
07:35 $ python3 test.py 
5H5D
```

Comment: That helps too O_O but that's like way too advanced for what I want.

Comment: If you think of it as "too advanced", you'll never want to learn it. Let me know what's confusing and I can explain a little more.

Comment: It's not confusing it's just this is to make a simple cards game, there's no need to be using libraries etc :P

Comment: `itertools` is in the standard library.

Comment: I know, I've tested it out.

Comment: Very well. Just know that your code is not idiomatic and you're writing much more code than you really need.

Comment: Everyone begins somewhere I guess

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though :)